# TortiseSVN 1.93 commit not showing all unversioned files but show up in ignored list

Tags: tortoisesvn

TortoiseSVN 1.93

Thought something was odd when I went to commit some changes, as one of the files I had added earlier was not showing up. One in particular is a .cs file in a class library project.  I thought this was odd, so I added a dummy test.txt file and then started a commit again, and even that text file was not in the list of unversioned files.

Usually, if there are unversioned files, I will see them and can add them right from the commit dialog.  There doesnt seem to be anything in my ignore list that would prevent these files from showing up. However, if I check for modifications, and choose the "Ignored" checkbox, sure enough, both of those files are in the list, among others.

Whats going on here?

Here is my ignore list:

> bin obj debug *.o *.suo *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a
>   *.pyc *.pyo **pycache** *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store [Tt]humbs.db

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checked the SVN properties on the folder where these files were located, and there was an svn:global-ignores property set to reference the entire folder.  Removed that, and opened a commit dialog again and those files were listed.  So somehow, I must have got a little too ambitious with setting things to be ignored.